# Recover 5 year old ethers from old wallet

Tags: wallets, recovery

I have an older (~5 years) ETH wallet I stashed away. Everything's changed so much since then, wonder if someone would clue me in on how to go about recovery.

I know the wallet address, I've verified the currency still exists there. I have my keystore folder with the key file. I don't have the password (back then I believe they were on passwords and not passphrases) but I'm pretty sure I can guess it without much trouble.

So, how do I go about this now? What current wallet software might support loading of the old keyfile, allowing me to enter the password, and finally managing the available funds once the password is correct?

Comment: Don’t give your file key to anyone even without password ... they will steal your money.. if it is a pre sold wallet, then there is a python code to try the password and get private key

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to load up your wallet fine with no issues on MyCrypto. We have a desktop version to download from our website. Full instructions on how to load it is listed here: https://support.mycrypto.com/how-to/accessing-wallet/how-to-access-your-wallet-with-keystore-file

Hope this helps and if you encounter any errors along the way - feel free to contact our support team at support@mycrypto.com

- Chris

Answer (score 0):

Actually when you uninstall eth Wallet your address move to other diversion path there are 100k + addresses there if you have file you can export recovery words and use https://iancoleman.io/bip39/
If you don't know diversion path check profile for more information about diversion Path

Comment: Ethereum Wallet didn't support BIP39 mnemonics.